# printing pandas in spyder / PyCharm rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, printing, spyder

I've tried to print some rows from my data set and for some reason not all the rows are displayed in the same line.

Bonus should be aligned with the other stats.
[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can persetting those style option by using [set_option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html)

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)
```

Comment: can i define it through preferences or settings and not as an online command? though it works, won't deny it.

Comment: @Talis i think you can do it

Comment: @Talis I think that is in setting of pycharm , also if it help would you like accept it ? check mark at the right

Comment: @Talis I am on pycharm , for spyder , you can just running those code when you start a console